# Change how Tumblr default theme shows page links

Tags: html, css, themes, default, tumblr

I want to change the way [Tumblr default theme](https://www.tumblr.com/theme/37310) shows the pages links (just under the Title and Description.

Some time ago it just showed all the links and if they didn't fit on one line, they just went to the next line.

Currently there is only one line of links that needs to be scrolled horizontaly using click n drag (or sliding with the finger in smartphones).

I want to change it as before so all the links can be shown without needing to scroll.

Comment: Where is your code what have you tried so far? I am confused as to why this question has been voted on.

Comment: @lharby I'm talking about the code of the tumblr default theme. You have the code here: https://paste.ofcode.org/PQTsGmw36RDJZQECNXLjgv

Answer (score 0):

I am having to guess here as you have not provided any code or an example, but if you want to show post tags stacked on top of one another (like a list).

Then change this code:

```
.inline-meta .meta-item {
   display:inline-block;
   ...
}
```

to this:

```
.inline-meta .meta-item {
   display:block;
   ...
}
```

Or write your own style tags as this css is inherited I believe.

So at the bottom of your style tag just add the property `display:block` to the `.inline-meta .meta-item` element.